# Run Django in DEBUG mode with Daphne

Tags: python, django, daphne

Need help to run django app with daphne in DEBUG mode with pycharm.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 3):

File: run_daphne.py

```py
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # insert here whatever commands you use to run daphne
    sys.argv = ['daphne', 'you_app.asgi:application']
    from daphne.cli import CommandLineInterface

    CommandLineInterface.entrypoint()
```

We are essentially doing the same thing as daphne command line just from python. Now you can run this file with PyCharm debugger.

Note that if you are using Django-Channels the `runserver` command will use daphne by default.

Comment: I made debug enviromnent in vscode from this! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the python debugger it will stop your code wherever you put this.

```
Some Code--
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
--Some Code
```

It will stop execution here and to proceed use "n" one by one.